# Getting the request body of search response with 2.X NEST client

Tags: elasticsearch, ninject, nest, glimpse

I'm using the new 2.X NEST client. That part is important, because there were a great many breaking changes which will effect potential answers here.

Previously, I used the Glimpse Elasticsearch plugin to see the underlying queries being generated by NEST. However, it would appear that that plugin is no longer compatible with 2.X NEST. As a result, I'm trying to find a workaround to see the JSON query. The problem here is that the old way of accessing `response.RequestInformation` to get at the request body is gone. It seems to have been replaced with a combination of `ApiCall`, `CallDetails`, and `DebugInformation`. The problem here is that in all of these the request byte array is null unless you add `.DisableDirectStreaming()` to the `ConnectionSettings` instance you pass into `ElasticClient`. The problem there is that I'm handling all that using dependency injection with Ninject, so in something like a controller action, I have no access to the `ConnectionSettings` instance to make such a change. I suppose I could just add `.DisableDirectStreaming()` globally, but I have no idea what the potential consequences of that is and the documentation on this is frustratingly sparse.

So, there's a few avenues for an answer here, any of which I'll accept. First, if anyone has manage to get the Glimpse plugin functioning with 2.X, I'd love to know what you did. However, based on the fact that the underlying API has changed dramatically, my assumption is that the plugin is fundamentally broken until someone branches it for 2.X or Elastic comes out with their own version (which is supposedly coming at some undetermined point in the future).

Second, if there's some way to get at the request body without disabling direct streaming, and I simply missed it. I'd appreciate guidance there.

Third, if anyone has any ideas for how I can disable direct streaming at the controller action level, without affecting my Ninject setup or applying it globally, feel free to chime in.

Finally, it would be great if someone from the Elastic team can enlighten me to the effects of disabling direct streaming and what potential problems can arise from that, so I can make a determination about whether it would be wise to apply it globally or not.

Answer (score 4):

With `.DisableDirectStreaming()` set to true, the request bytes and response bytes are buffered in memory streams to enable them to be available on the response via `response.RequestBodyInBytes` and `response.ResponseBodyInBytes`, respectively.

By default, it is set to false so the request type e.g. `SearchDescriptor<T>`, `SearchRequest<T>`, etc. is serialized directly to the request stream of the http request and similarly, the response type is deserialized from the response stream. The overhead of setting it to true is therefore keeping the request and response bytes around in memory for the lifetime of the response (and GC kicking in).

With Connection Settings, it's best to have one instance for the lifetime of the application; Serialization settings are cached per connection settings as well as caches for field and property expressions. There's no way currently to keep the request and response bytes around on a per request basis i.e. ad-hoc introspection, but I think this would be a useful addition; I'll add an issue for it :)

I'm not personally overly familiar with the Glimpse integration but I would expect it would require updating to work with NEST 2.x because of some of the changes. Having just given it a brief look, the changes look pretty straightforward. Looks like this can be done without having to set `.DisableDirectStreaming()` to true, but only grabbing the request bytes before they're written to the request stream.

Comment: Since this answer, it is possible to disable direct streaming on a per request basis in NEST 5.x - will look to see if it can be backported to 2.x

Comment: For those looking for this information, you can find it here - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/debug-information.html - the `SearchDescriptor` accepts `RequestConfiguration`