# How Do I View the REST JSON created by the NEST API?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to find the place in the NEST API (or via the underlying ElasticSearch.NET API at the time of using NEST) where I can see the JSON created by a NEST query. This is my problem summed up in a partial code sample -

```
using NEST;

// create any query 
var elasticResponse = elasticClient.Search<Hotel>(s => s
   .Query(q => // ... build up the rest of my query ... 

elasticResponse.ApiCall.HttpMethod // is "POST" - good! 
elasticResponse.ApiCall.HttpStatusCode // is 200 (OKAY) - good! 
elasticResponse.ApiCall.Success // is true - good! 

// ISSUE: 
// I've tried viewing the generated JSON through these members (in no particular order) without success ... 

elasticResponse.ApiCall.RequestBodyInBytes // is always empty before and after use of the elasticResponse object. 

elasticResponse.ApiCall.DebugInformation // doesn't provide useful info about body. 

elasticResponse.CallDetails.RequestBodyInBytes // is always null.
```

I'm using Elastic Search 2.3.1 and NEST 2.4.1.

The places in which I expect to see the POST data or generated query don't have it; they are either empty or null, and no error condition is showing because the query was successful.

I have also looked through available members of the query descriptor while building up the query, with the thought I might be able to capture the RESTful call body immediately after I finish building the query, but haven't found anything useful yet.

`ConnectionSettings` turn up a `.OnRequestCompleted`callback but that doesn't seem to reveal the query either.

I've skimmed the official [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/index.html) to no avail yet.  Looking for some help. Thank you.

Comment: Closely related is this question that involves Glimpse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105355/getting-the-request-body-of-search-response-with-2-x-nest-client

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found one answer through use of configuration settings -

Set `ConnectionSettings`(instance) Disable Direct Streaming property to `true` with `.DisableDirectStreaming(true);` and pass it to your new Elastic NEST client object.   This will tell Elastic to buffer request and response and cause both values to become available on the `.RequestBodyInBytes` and `.ResponseBodyInBytes` properties respectively.

You can then decode the bytes using .NET e.g.

```
global::System.Text.UTF8Encoding.Default.GetString(elasticResponse.ApiCall.RequestBodyInBytes);
```

and see the original query, for example in my  case -

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "shortDescription": {
                    "value": "mile"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "shortDescription": {
                    "value": "museum"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "name": {
                    "boost": 1.1,
                    "value": "pacific"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Additional note - this setting is represented on the low-level client as `Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticLowLevelClient` instance `.Settings.DisableDirectStreaming(true);`